# Can we use existing build script in Teamcity?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

We are developing .net applications and using Clearcase for our SCM needs.

We have build script written in Msbuild. Can we use our existing script as it is in Teamcity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, TeamCity supports MSBuild runners, please see http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/MSBuild